# Problems finding the QObject header in project. Am I doing something wrong in my CMAKE?

Tags: c++, qt

This is what my CMAKE looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project (SELENA LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:/Qt/6.4.0/msvc2019_64/lib/cmake/Qt6")
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:/Qt/6.4.0/msvc2019_64/include")

#set(CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES "x86_64;arm64")

find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core)

add_library(SELENA STATIC 

SaAbstraction.cpp
SaAbstraction.h
SaAccelerationMgr.cpp
SaAccelerationMgr.h
SaApp.cpp
SaApp.h
SaAtomicAbstraction.cpp
SaAtomicAbstraction.h
SaBase.cpp
SaBase.h
SaContextBuffer.cpp
SaContextBuffer.h
SaImpression.cpp
SaImpression.h
SaIntegrationMgr.cpp
SaIntegrationMgr.h
SaMetagraph.cpp
SaMetagraph.h
SaNode.cpp
SaNode.h
SaOperator.cpp
SaOperator.h
SaPathFile.cpp
SaPathFile.h
SaSynapse.cpp
SaSynapse.h
SaToken.cpp
SaToken.h
SaTrainer.cpp
SaTrainer.h
main.cpp
)

target_include_directories(SELENA PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

# Link against Qt 6 libraries
target_link_libraries(SELENA PRIVATE Qt6::Core)

# Define the target "SelenaDemo"
add_executable(SelenaDemo main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(SelenaDemo SELENA)
```

I keep getting this error in VC 2020:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C1083   Cannot open include file: 'QObject': No such file or directory  SelenaDemo  D:\Twilight Raven Games Checkouts\SELENA_CODE\src\SaBase.h  20

This is what SaBase.h looks like:

```
/************************************************************
The SELENA Impression Architecture
By Walter Gress
Property of Twilight Raven Games LLC
*************************************************************/

#pragma once



/************************************************************
CLASS BLURB

The SaBase class is used as common parent class for all 
classes in the SELENA Application. It provides an interface
to the QOBJECT class.

************************************************************/

#include <QObject>

class SaBase : public QObject
{

    Q_OBJECT

public:

    SaBase();
    ~SaBase();
};
```

I've made sure #pragma once is in every header file, I've tried regenerating using CMake-GUI instead of building ZERO_CHECK.

Comment: `target_link_libraries(SELENA PRIVATE Qt6::Core)` needs to be `target_link_libraries(SELENA PUBLIC Qt6::Core)` if any file in the `SelenaDemo` project includes `SaBase.h`

Answer (score 3):

Yes you are doing 1 unexpected thing wrong.

Your problem is:

```
target_link_libraries(SELENA PRIVATE Qt6::Core)
```

This makes the include directories for the Qt framework only available for the `SELENA` library target and not for any target that depends on SELENA.

However your `SaBase.h` header includes `QObject` which requires that the Qt include directories are inherited by the dependent project.

You instead need:

```
target_link_libraries(SELENA PUBLIC Qt6::Core)
```

so that the files in `SelenaDemo`  can include `SaBase.h`